# What must be changed in given formula to change feet & inches to meters for Non-Decimal numbers

Tags: excel, excel-formula

The given formula works as expected for decimal numbers ie If my input is 8.3 (8 foot 3 inches) then the formula below works but it does not works for a Non-Decimal numbers.For eg:If my input is 4 only or even 4.0 then the **VALUE** *error* appears.
What changes should be made on the formula such that it works for non decimal numbers too.

```
=(LEFT(B5,FIND(".",B5)-1)*12+SUBSTITUTE(MID(B5,FIND(".",B5)+1,LEN(B5)),"""",""))/39.3701
```

Comment: Can you show us an example of yoiur input plz - it looks as though it has an inch symbol on the end, e.g.8.3" ? Also does the 3 in 8.3 definitely mean 3" (so 8.11 would mean 8 feet and 11 inches)?

Comment: Your data can be ambiguous. If `8.3` = `8 ft 3 in` how would you differentiate `8 ft 1 in` from `8 ft 10 in`?  Are you always entering data as a Text String?  Or are you entering it as a number.  If the latter, you will need to enter `8.03`.

Comment: @RonRosenfeld Did'nt thought about that.You are correct. `8.1` and `8.10` gives same value.How can it be solved ? Also Is there a way around in formula such that `8.3` works instead of typing `8.03`.

Comment: @You could ensure that all numbers are entered as Text strings, and then do some complicated parsing with text functions; or resolve to enter single digit inches with the leading zero. Then the conversion becomes simpler.

Comment: @TomSharpe Yes, 8.11 means (8 feet and 11 inches ).The inch is in formula and the formula works fine with or without it.The main difference that i just found is that if i keep the inch in the end then `8.1` and `8.10` gives exact results.If inch symbol is not included then `8.1` and `8.10` gives similar results.Without including inch symbol in input how can the answers be achieved through the formula ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are entering the values as numbers, and are placing a leading zero in front of the single digit inches (e.g 8.03) then a formula to convert to meters:

```
=CONVERT(DOLLARDE(B5,12),"ft","m")
```

If you are entering them as text strings (and without the `"` sign), you can use:

```
=MAX(IF((LEN(B7) - FIND(".",B7&"."))={-1,2}, CONVERT(DOLLARDE(B7,12),"ft","m")),IFERROR(CONVERT(DOLLARDE(INT(B7) &".0" & MID(B7,FIND(".",B7)+1,1),12),"ft","m"),0))
```

There is no method of which I am aware that you can enter `8.1` as a number and have Excel **know**  if you mean `8 ft 1 in` or `8 ft 10 in`

Answer (score 1):

Per Ron Rosenfeld above entering your values as 8.01 and 8.10 respectively.
[image]